# Compressing string stored in session storage

Tags: javascript, session, storage

I have a large string that is getting stored in session storage and at some point it gets sent to a server. The string gets quite large sometime (up wards of 2mb). Are there any compression algorithms I can use to reduce the size?

Comment: Reduce the size when you send it, or while it is stored?

Comment: Have you tried http://code.google.com/p/jslzjb/ ?

Comment: Reduce the size while it is stored preferably

Comment: HTTP supports DEFLATE *responses*, however, I do not believe there is any "standard" for uploading. I would suggest sticking with the DEFLATE/ZLIB/GZIP/ZIP line (they all use DEFLATE) because it's 1) common 2) generally quite good. Just be aware of re-inflation to send "zipped" (e.g. binary data) over a re-encoded text stream.

Comment: Of course, depending on the data, it might make sense just to look at/alter the encoding used ..

Comment: I tried jsLZJB but it converts the string into a set of numbers, and storing that inside the session storage as a string would take more space!

Comment: Session storage is always on the server side isn't it?  The client only needs the session key which is passed to the server to get the data, no?

Comment: This is Javascript SessionStorage (HTML5) on client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work by using DEFLATE javascript library at https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate and compress the string on the client side and then decompress on the server side using the same algorithm.

This function works really well in firefox and chrome but is very slow in IE. The compressed string is 15% the size of the original!

Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/mwolfetech/X2NL6 for an example